# How to prevent my site from opening in any other browser apart from chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

When the link is opened or copy pasted in any browser apart from chrome, the page should not load is there any it can be done using Javascript of Java? I want my web application to be used only in chrome. Kindly help

Thank you

Comment: javascript and java <--- Huge difference, it's like you are keeping Firefox and Internet Explorer

Comment: I want ot make it in CSS or in Rails.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is a better way to do what you want, than to lock out two thirds of all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Browser Detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) would be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work for you:
http://www.netzwelt-kali.de/index.php?menuid=28&reporeid=67

Answer (score 1):

This is quite ugly. However, here's some way to do that :

- sniffing User Agent with JS with something like Browser detection : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

or just with CSS :

```
body * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { /* Target only Chrome */
  body * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

I definitly don't know why you don't want users to come to your app with their favorite browser.

Comment: Besides, Javascript or CSS is no solution. All the user needs to do is disable the bit that performs the test, for instance with a tool like GreaseMonkey or something. To do it properly, you'd use server side web sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend making a website for only one browser.

However, here are two options for browser detection:

[A browser detector](https://github.com/ded/bowser)

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)